# Books on Vector Analysis similar to C.E. Weatherburn

Tags: reference-request, vector-analysis, self-learning, book-recommendation

I have both *Elementary Vector Analysis* and *Advanced Vector Analysis* by C.E. Weatherburn, but these books have been compiled many years ago. And whilst some books relevant to over 50 years ago may still be relevant to today. I presume there has been new information in Vector Analysis (Or it may be a new term altogether).

I am requesting for recommendations of books that are recent but similar to the books mentioned, however, with more information. These books are rather small by pagination, and I feel these omit important information for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

The first book you mention has an edition from 2013.

I suggest a book in vector analysis that also has tensor calculus. The book I had was in 1994 and in Swedish. Tensors are nothing new.

Anyway this book from Springer in Amazon seem to have interesting contents: Tensor and Vector Analysis: With Applications to Differential Geometry (Dover Books on Mathematics)

[https://www.amazon.com/Tensor-Vector-Analysis-Applications-Differential/dp/0486498018](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486498018)

Comment: That edition is most likely an exact reprint of the original edition. Do you have a link to it?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Charles-Ernest-Weatherburn-ebook/dp/B00BR23I2M/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=Elementary+Vector+Analysis&qid=1595678587&sr=8-1